# Vue-i18n - Issue with dynamic localizations from http request

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, vue-ssr

I m trying to load the localization from HTTP call as i want the languages to be dynamic and manageable, rather than shipping it with the application.

I did a work around using the SSR sample and some of my own implementation. But on the initial render the language does not loading. When changing the route client-side things are getting updated.

**i18n.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import en from './en.json'
import ar from './ar.json'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const fallbackLocale = 'en'
let defaultLocale = 'ar'

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: defaultLocale, // set locale
  fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale,
  messages: {
    'en': en
  }
})

export function createI18n () {
  return i18n
}
```

**Router - router.beforeEach**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (router.app.$store) {
        router.app.$store
          .dispatch('getI18nData')
          .then(function(){
            router.app.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('ar',router.app.$store.getters.getLocale)
            return next()
          })
          .catch(() => console.log('getI18nData-error'))
      } else {
        next()
      }
  })
```

**Store Action - to fetch locale**

```
getI18nData ({ commit }) {
   try {
     axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lang?lang=ar')
    .then(function (response) {
      let locale = response.data
      commit('setLocale', { locale })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error:getI18nData')
    })
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
 }
```

**Findings:**
i18n is initializing before `router.beforeEach` where it should initialize after `router.beforeEach`.

[Github Issue Link](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/372)

Comment: Return a promise from `getI18nData`.   `return axios.get(...` works, or make it async by other means, like `async getI18nData(...){...`  and `await axios.get`. Right now it continues immediately after firing off dispatch because no promise was returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, to be a little bit more detailed: You don't want to mix try/catch with your promise-chain, but you need to return a promise from `getI18nData` or dispatch won't wait. So you either:

```
getI18nData ({ commit }) {
    // axios.get() returns a promise already, so we can just return the whole thing:
    return axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080/lang?lang=ar')
      .then(function (response) {
        let locale = response.data
        commit('setLocale', { locale })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error:getI18nData')
      });
}
```

Or your use async/await (which does allow try/catch):

```
async getI18nData ({ commit }) {
  try {
    let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lang?lang=ar');
    let locale = response.data
    commit('setLocale', { locale })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I'd like to add that I do like the async/await option better, but in vuex-land it usually leads to you having to make everything async/await (if you use nested dispatch calls). So depending on the rest of your code-base, it might be easier to just return the promise.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the flaw, even though i dispatched a promise still it was not working. So along with the promise dispatch i had make one more changes to the code which is `router.beforeEach` i had to replace it with `router.beforeResolve` and now everything seems to be working fine.